# assemble short peptides based on their location on long peptides in r

Tags: r, dna-sequence

I have the data like the following:

long_pep short_pep start end

> DADLADGVSGGEGKGGSDGGGSHRKEGEEADAPGVIPGIVG DADLADGVSGGEGK  1   14
> DADLADGVSGGEGKGGSDGGGSHRKEGEEADAPGVIPGIVG GGSDGGGSHR  15  24
> DADLADGVSGGEGKGGSDGGGSHRKEGEEADAPGVIPGIVG KEGEEADAPGVIPGIVG   25  41
> DADLADGVSGGEGKGGSDGGGSHRKEGEEADAPGVIPGIVG KEGEEADAPGVI    25  36
> DADLADGVSGGEGKGGSDGGGSHRKEGEEADAPGVIPGIVG KEGEEADAPGVIP   25  37
> DGVSGGEGKGGSDGGGSHRKEGEEADAPGVIPG DGVSGGEGK   1   9
> DGVSGGEGKGGSDGGGSHRKEGEEADAPGVIPG GVSGGEGK    2   9
> DGVSGGEGKGGSDGGGSHRKEGEEADAPGVIPG GGSDGGGSHR  10  19
> DGVSGGEGKGGSDGGGSHRKEGEEADAPGVIPG KEGEEADAPGVIPG  20  33
> AAHLIFCCFRDLCNSEL AAHLIFCCFR  1   10 AAHLIFCCFRDLCNSEL    AHLIFCCFR   2   10
> AAHLIFCCFRDLCNSEL DLCNSEL 11  17

I want to assemble the peptide sequences in “short_pep” column in R based on the sequence in the first column “long_pep” , “start” and “end” columns where the corresponding “end”  value for the first short peptide in assembly =  (the corresponding “start” value for the second short_pep in assembly - 1) and so on for the 3rd and other short peptides in assembly.
I tried to use "inner join" function which is not helping me to get like the following in only one step:

```
long_pep assembled_short_pep start  end

DADLADGVSGGEGKGGSDGGGSHRKEGEEADAPGVIPGIVG   DADLADGVSGGEGK_GGSDGGGSHR_KEGEEADAPGVIPGIVG 1   41

DADLADGVSGGEGKGGSDGGGSHRKEGEEADAPGVIPGIVG   DADLADGVSGGEGK_GGSDGGGSHR_KEGEEADAPGVI  1   36

DADLADGVSGGEGKGGSDGGGSHRKEGEEADAPGVIPGIVG   DADLADGVSGGEGK_GGSDGGGSHR_KEGEEADAPGVIP 1   37

DGVSGGEGKGGSDGGGSHRKEGEEADAPGVIPG   DGVSGGEGK_GGSDGGGSHR_KEGEEADAPGVIPG 1   33

DGVSGGEGKGGSDGGGSHRKEGEEADAPGVIPG   GVSGGEGK_GGSDGGGSHR_KEGEEADAPGVIPG  2   33

AAHLIFCCFRDLCNSEL   AAHLIFCCFR_DLCNSEL  1   17

AAHLIFCCFRDLCNSEL   AHLIFCCFR_DLCNSEL   2   17
```

Comment: are you aware of https://www.bioconductor.org/ ? It has a huge array of bioinformatic tools coded in R.

Comment: @Ben Bolker; thanks so much for your answer. but, do you know which package in Bioconductor has functions that could work for such problem

Comment: I don't; I just thought it might be worth looking there.